# JPA to_char function for date in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, datetime-format

I have this query and an oracle DB. When I try to execute it, I never receive an answer from DB. Edit: Query return 0 rows. I know that is for Date because if I use the same query with TO_CHAR with Toad this works. How i can add in Java code TO_CHAR function? Thank you.

```
       public List<PrivacySospensiva> getAllByCf(String cf,Long idsuperpratica,String stato,Date dataCensimento){
            TypedQuery<PrivacySospensiva> query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from PrivacySospensiva u where u.id_superpratica = :idSuperpratica AND u.stato = :stato AND u.cf = :cf AND u.data_censimento = :dataCensimento", PrivacySospensiva.class);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mm:SS");
            sdf.format(dataCensimento);
            query.setParameter("idSuperpratica", idsuperpratica);
            query.setParameter("stato",stato);
            query.setParameter("cf",cf);
            query.setParameter("dataCensimento",dataCensimento);
            List<PrivacySospensiva> result = query.getResultList();
            return result;

       }
```

Comment: Don't pass dates as strings, pass them as instances of `java.sql.Timestamp`

Comment: `I never receive an answer from DB`. Wonder what that means

Comment: @DN1 Query return 0 row.

Comment: Thanks for adding precision to the statement. Please always do that in the question (you’ve got [an edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48579577/edit) under it) rather than in a comment.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Agree to pass date-times as objects rather than strings. However, `Timestamp` is long outdated, better to use a class from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. See for example [How To Map The Date And Time API with JPA 2.2](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/map-date-time-api-jpa-2-2/). Search for more.

Comment: @OleV.V.: I agree, but are you sure that this works with the Oracle JDBC driver? Because it does not work if you use standard JDBC API calls, only if you use Oracle specific methods The last time I checked e.g. `setObject(..., java.time.LocalDateTime)` failed with the Oracle driver. So it would require the obfuscation layer to know about the quirks in each and every driver

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, no, I haven’t tried. What you say surprises me negatively as long as Java also comes from Oracle…

Comment: @OleV.V.: there are other parts where the driver blatantly ignores the JDBC specification and Oracle claims that it's not a bug. Apparently the JDBC driver developers don't care about the Java/JDBC standards that Oracle itself defines

Answer (score 0):

The date format is wrong and should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` (0-23 hours) or `yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss` (1-24 hours). And SS would be microseconds.

Fortunately the code does not use it; all probably an experiment. One would need to do:

```
String t = sdf.format(dataCensimento);
query.setParameter("dataCensimento", t);
```

(`sdf.format` will not alter `dataCensimento`.)